# C++: overloading a function with a void* function with functions with specific(double...) pointer parameter

Tags: c++, overloading

Is it possible to overload a function with a void pointer:

```
void setValue(void* value) { 
}
```

with a function with a specific pointer`?

```
void setValue(double* value) { 
}
```

How will be the behaviour of such overloaded functions, if we pass a void* value.

```
void* lvalue;
setValue(lvalue);
```

and if we pass a specific pointer:

```
double* lvalue;
setValue(lvalue);
```

Will this work like expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Yes.](http://ideone.com/2RYOuR)

```
#include <iostream>

void f(double* ptr) { std::cout << "DOUBLE\n"; }
void f(void* ptr) { std::cout << "VOID\n"; }

int main()
{
    void* v = nullptr;
    double* d = nullptr;
    f(v);
    f(d);
    // f(nullptr); // fails to compile
    // f(NULL); // fails to compile
}
```

Outputs:

```
VOID
DOUBLE
```

Now, if you want `f(nullptr)` to compile, add `f(std::nullptr_t)` overload.

Answer (score 1):

`void*` and `double*` are distinct types, so overloading should work as expected.